# How to get all application name added in Scecurity & Privacy Accessbility in Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have 2 applications. for example Main application & Sub application.

I have to add grant acessbility permission to Sub application (It is using some hardware functionality).

When i launch Main app, i need to check if Sub application name is added in Security & Privacy -> Accessbility or not.

I am not able to find any help to get list of all items added in Accessbility page.

Kindly help.

Thank you all.